# Can I run some custom script after ASP.NET client side page validation fails?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to run some client side script if, *and only if*, the client side Page validation fails, and can't figure out where I can hook it in.

If i bind my JavaScript function to the OnClientClick of the button that submits the form, it runs before the client side validation. If I bind it to the OnSubmit of the form, that only fires if the validation passes.

Any ideas of how or where I can hook something like this up? Or if you have other suggestions, I'm open to them.

```
<form id="frm" runat="server" 
     onsubmit="FUNCTION HERE WONT FIRE IF VALIDATION FAILS">
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="vld" runat="server" controltovalidate="txt"/>
<asp:textbox id="txt" runat="server"></asp:textbox>

<asp:button id="cmd" runat="server" OnClick="dosomething"
     OnClientClick="FUNCTION FIRES BEFORE VALIDATION OCCURS">

</form>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `Page_ClientValidate("")` to trigger validation from JavaScript, and then you can run some custom code:

```
validate = function(){
    var isValid = Page_ClientValidate(""); //parameter is the validation group - thanks @Jeff
    if (isValid){
        isValid = somethingToCheck();
    }
    return isValid;
}

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return validate();" ... />
```

Comment: Beat me to it! @Doozer, the parameter is the validation group so if you are using one, you'll need to pass that in: `Page_ClientValidate("MyValidationGroup")`

Comment: Ah... this looks like the right path. In your example, would I set Button1 to CausesValidation="false", or will that matter?

Comment: @DoozerBlake: Hmm, if you don't want validation to key off until you call `Page_ClientValidate("")` then I would say YES to setting `CausesValidation="false"`, tentatively.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter either way. I tried it with both, and OnClientClick appears to fire off before the Validation happens. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just don't miss the part where you put in the validationGroup to the Page_ClientValidate parameter.

Answer (score 16):

Add script below at the end of page's markup file:

```
var originalValidationFunction = Page_ClientValidate;
if (originalValidationFunction && typeof (originalValidationFunction) == "function") {
    Page_ClientValidate = function (validationGroup) {
        originalValidationFunction(validationGroup);

        if (!Page_IsValid) {
            // your code here
            alert("oops!");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer cause it doesn't force me to control the validation myself, only piggyback afterward.

Comment: This is the best solution I found.

Comment: Not working for me.  I can see in the debugger it only gets called with validationGroup set to empty string, not being called for other validation groups, Page_IsValid is true when it reaches the if and then becomes false as you exit the function.

Comment: Plus I don't think this code is correct.   Page_ClientValidate returns true or false, the overriding function should return the value returned by  originalValidationFunction

Answer (score 2):

So you have two options how to handle it:

1. Use  [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) validator which provides [ClientValidationFunction](http://CustomValidator.ClientValidationFunction) feature and inside your custom validation function obviously you know whether validation failed. It gives you as much as you need flexibility on client side validation by accepting a JavaScript function to be used whilst validation.
2. Check validator satus by accessing it via JavaScript by accessing validator's isValid property from JavaScript (+jQuery):

```
 var anonymousValidator = $("#<%= vldCommentText.ClientID %>")[0];
 ValidatorEnable(anonymousValidator, true);
 if (!anonymousValidator.isvalid) 
 {
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: I'm aware of CustomValidator's, but how would I know within this CustomValidator function if every other validator on the page is valid? The example above uses one field, but the form I have in question has 20+ validators on it. Would I have to check their status first?

Comment: @Doozer Blake : good point which you've to mention in the original question. SO to check status of a multiple validators Validation Groups feature is in place. See Nice article by Scott Gu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific about that. Thank you for your help though.