# how do I get the validationsummary text to put in a custom alert ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

for a recent schoolproject I need to make an ASP-website.
On the loginform I have a few validators and a validationsummary.

The summary itself works, but I would like to get the text from it,
so I could put it into my own custom "popup". The popup is just a twitter-bootstrap model wich I tweaked a bit so I can put in a title and some text easily from any code behind file.

Can anybody help me? Any c# code behind, or jquery solution is fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution in this answer:
[Can I run some custom script after ASP.NET client side page validation fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692289/can-i-run-some-custom-script-after-asp-net-client-side-page-validation-fails)

Basically you call the Page_ClientValidate("") function and write custom JavaScript to display the alert

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I would like to use the built-in validators of ASP, instead of building a custom javascript/jquery validation.

Comment: You are not building custom validation. You are running the validation with Page_ClientValidate. It runs the validators that are already on the page.